# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/conn/SchemePortResolver with AmazonHttpClient

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

All

I am running into this error in my project when I updated aws library to the latest 1.11.3.

Caused by:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/conn/SchemePortResolver
at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheHttpClientFactory.<init>(ApacheHttpClientFactory.java:40)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.<clinit>(AmazonHttpClient.java:97)
at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.<init>(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:145)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<init>(AmazonS3Client.java:393)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<init>(AmazonS3Client.java:373)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<init>(AmazonS3Client.java:355)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<init>(AmazonS3Client.java:339)
```

in my pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-kms</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
          <artifactId>bcprov-ext-jdk15on</artifactId>
         <version>1.54</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
         <artifactId>aws-encryption-sdk-java</artifactId>
          <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

Anyone know what I did wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had a similar issue with my grails application.  In my case the ClassNotFoundException was being thrown from a deploy script.  For me the reason SchemePortResolver wasn't being resolved implicitly was because it wasn't required at compile time, it was needed at runtime.  Here's what I added to my BuildConfig.groovy to fix it:

```
runtime 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.2' //Required by BeanstalkDeploy.groovy at runtime
```

Since the OP's question was for Maven, here's the equivalent include:

```
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
   <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
   <version>4.5.2</version>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
 </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you add,

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
  <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
  <version>4.5.2</version>
 </dependency>
```

,it should work ok as it contains the missing class definitions.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In addition to including the code that will work, please include some text as to why this works.

Comment: same error here trying to upgrade my sdk to 1.11.15 for spark-redshift package but getting same error also. adding httpclient dep to pom did not help. Any further luck with this?

Answer (score 1):

A common cause would be a Maven dependency conflict. In the example below (`pom.xml` as viewed in Eclipse's *Dependency Hierarchy* tab), the POM explicitly includes v4.1 of `httpclient`, which forces Maven to omit the v4.5.5 that aws-java-sdk-core requires (and thus, causes the similar error *java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/conn/DnsResolver at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheHttpClientFactory...*):

[image: Screenshot of Eclipse Dependency Hierarchy]

Comment: From the command line you can use `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` to get similar information.

Comment: How could I fix it?

Comment: It depends on the specifics of your case. If the conflict is because of a dependency in your own code, you could upgrade that dependency - which may or may not require changes to your code. If the conflict is because of a dependency brought in by some other library that your code depends on, then you could use an `<exclusion>` for old httpclient version in the `<dependency>`, in your POM - but there is a chance that the code which depended on the old version will no longer function correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I delete the .meta file in eclipse workplace then import the project again thereafter it work like a charm.
Could not know where the problem exactly.
Before delete .meta I add all files from
aws-java-sdk-1.11.606\third-party\lib